# php or html, css and js

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am programming a school website where I want an easy system for teachers, where they could post news, informations, etc. I also want a timetable there. Which language is best suited for these needs?

Thanks
Adam

Comment: You would probably have to use a few languages, JS, PHP, HTML. Also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You should learn what is a static website and what is dynamic website. Then decide which one you want to create.
In your description you wrote:

> I am programming a school website where I want an easy system for
>   teachers, where they could post news, informations, etc. I also want a
>   timetable there. Which language is best suited for these needs?

You basically asked for a site in which teachers could post things like news, informations, etc. That's a dynamic content. Therefor you will need php and mysql database to create something like this. Whereas to design the layout of the website you will need html, css and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to learn https://moodle.org/ ( this's open source )  if you can not create their own learning website

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of system, you'd probably use a [client-server architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).

Client is programmed in client languages (like HTML, JS, CSS and many others).

Server is programmed in server languages (like PHP, and many others).